# AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId Security Token Service Credentials are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using **Security Token Service** to generate credentials `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` to pass it to the client side. I am able to generate credentials successfully. But, when I use dynamically generated credentials I got this error

```
AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records
```

Followings are the steps I have used to generate credentials with Security Token Service

**Create Role**
I have created a role on AWS with following policy (to list and upload files on AWS S3 bucket)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Edit Trust Relationship**
I have edited trust relationship to assign role to the `IAM` user

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:user/<user_name>"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

**How I am generating credentials**

```
sts = Aws::STS::Client.new
session = sts.assume_role(role_arn: 'arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/<role_name>', role_session_name: 'test_session')
@aws_access_key_id = session.credentials.access_key_id
@aws_secret_access_key = session.credentials.secret_access_key
@aws_security_token = session.credentials.session_token
@expires_at = session.credentials.expiration
```

I am able to generated credentials but credentials are invalid.

Thanks

Comment: How did you verify that your credentials are valid? Show your code on how you are using the credentials. The key with STS temporary credentials is to pass the security token correctly. Also, make sure that you are not using Root credentials in the call to Assume Role.

Comment: I am using chrome S3 Browser extension to upload and view files, also make sure connecting in terminal with those credentials but they aren't working ....

Yes I am not using root credentials in the call to assume role instead I am using IAM user credentials

Comment: *"The specified access and security key are invalid."*  Where do you see this?  This does not sound like a standard AWS error message, and there's no such thing as a "security key."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot "The specified access and security key are invalid." I am seeing this message in google chrome extension when I use newly created credentials.

Comment: It's confusing to me that when I google that phrase, in quotes, I find exactly one hit -- this question.  I am unfamiliar with the browser extension (though it sounds interesting) but note that the access key and secret from STS are indeed invalid unless the security token is also used with them.  Does this extension accept all three values?  If not, it is only compatible with IAM user credentials, not STS temporary credentials.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Now I tried using access_key, access_secret and session_token to upload file via `aws-sdk` gem in ruby not I get this error message **AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records**